Can anyone help me understand the concept of M2 in french masters? If i already have a 2years masters in a subject
I have a 3yr BSc and 2yr MSc in mathematics and I've done some work related to signal and computational mathematics but always wanted to do research in Astrophysics. Now in this case am I eligible to apply for M2 Astrophysics course? Omitting M1? Because I already have 4+years before. Please help me in this if someone has idea on this.

What question are you asking exactly? You are mixing question and affirmation which is not 100% clear.

A master in France is done in 2 years. M1 refers to the first year, while M2 refers to the second.
ECTS are used in university to facilitate migration between establishment and formation. You likely need to validate a certain number of them to be eligible for a second year course. If you have, then yes, you can likely directly do the Astrophysics course.
You can also be admitted into a M2 on direct application (it may depends on your university) and they will evaluate your profile. (candidature sur dossier)
You will likely receive better insight by the university you want to apply to (on how to apply, what are the requirements, etc)
